# Why HttpServletRequest is null in collection.parallelStream()

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was using spring-boot 1.2.7, I met a NullPointerException while trying to use this in a `parallelStream().forEach(o -> addAddtionalData(id))`, but `stream()` is ok, I think this maybe a thread issue, but I can't explain it well, Could anyone please help to guide me out?

```
private void addAddtionalData(Long id){

    // request is null but not the first time loop in parallel stream
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    boolean isSecure = request.isSecure();    
    // some code 
}
```

Exception:

```
[ERROR] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for 
servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
     at com.app.service.QuoteService.setAdditionalData(QuoteService.java:103) ~[classes/:na]
     at com.app.service.QuoteService.lambda$getAllQuotes$41(QuoteService.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
     at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
     at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
     at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RequestContextHolder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) uses a `ThreadLocal` to find the context object.

> Holder class to expose the web request in the form of a **thread-bound** [`RequestAttributes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestAttributes.html) object.

Using parallel streams means that your code is running in a different thread, so no context object.

You should get the `isSecure` value before starting your stream processing.